# Google Glass CameraService::connect X (pid ***) not ready to acquire camera 0

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

The code to open Google Glass Camera

```
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (camera == null){ 
               //I added the line and thought it may take time to get camera ready
            SystemClock.sleep(7000); 
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Number of cameras: " + Camera.getNumberOfCameras());
            camera = Camera.open();
        }
    }
```

Below is the error I got:

```
06-11 16:34:22.555: E/DS(29531): Number of cameras: 1
06-11 16:34:23.063: E/CameraService(253): Waited 501 ms but hardware teardown is still not finished!
06-11 16:34:23.063: E/CameraService(253): CameraService::connect X (pid 29531) not ready to acquire camera 0.
```